# Is DHCP request message a broadcast or Unicast?

Tags: networking, dhcp

DHCP process occurs in 4 stages as DORA. I know Discover and Offer are broadcast. Is DHCP request message a broadcast or Unicast?

Answer (score 2):

The DHCPOFFER and DHCPACK are normally sent from the server to the client as unicast. The client can set a Broadcast flag to request that the server send broadcast back to the client, but this is not the preferred method.

This is detailed in [*RFC 2131, Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131#section-4.1):

> In the case of a client using DHCP for initial configuration (before
> the client's TCP/IP software has been completely configured), DHCP
> requires creative use of the client's TCP/IP software and liberal
> interpretation of RFC 1122.  The TCP/IP software SHOULD accept and
> forward to the IP layer any IP packets delivered to the client's
> hardware address before the IP address is configured; DHCP servers and
> BOOTP relay agents may not be able to deliver DHCP messages to clients
> that cannot accept hardware unicast datagrams before the TCP/IP
> software is configured.
>
> To work around some clients that cannot accept IP unicast datagrams
> before the TCP/IP software is configured as discussed in the previous
> paragraph, DHCP uses the 'flags' field [21].  The leftmost bit is
> defined as the BROADCAST (B) flag.  The semantics of this flag are
> discussed in section 4.1 of this document.  The remaining bits of the
> flags field are reserved for future use.  They MUST be set to zero by
> clients and ignored by servers and relay agents.  Figure 2 gives the
> format of the 'flags' field.
>
> ```
>                              1 1 1 1 1 1
>          0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5
>          +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>          |B|             MBZ             |
>          +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
>
>           B:  BROADCAST flag
>
>           MBZ:  MUST BE ZERO (reserved for future use)
>
>           Figure 2:  Format of the 'flags' field
> ```

-and-

> Normally, DHCP servers and BOOTP relay agents attempt to deliver
> DHCPOFFER, DHCPACK and DHCPNAK messages directly to the client using
> uicast delivery.  The IP destination address (in the IP header) is set
> to the DHCP 'yiaddr' address and the link-layer destination address is
> set to the DHCP 'chaddr' address.  Unfortunately, some client
> implementations are unable to receive such unicast IP datagrams until
> the implementation has been configured with a valid IP address
> (leading to a deadlock in which the client's IP address cannot be
> delivered until the client has been configured with an IP address).

Answer (score 0):

It's a broadcast. DISCOVER, OFFER, REQUEST, ACK are all broadcast. Client does not get an IP address before the whole process is completed. So it has to broadcast. You can see more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol#DHCP_request).

Comment: Actually, the responses from the DHCP server are unicast by default. You must set the broadcast bit in the request to get broadcast responses. It's all detailed in the RFC.

Comment: @Ron Maupin: please excuse, I did not read the RFC, just checked my TCP/IP Illustrated， it says responses from the server(OFFER and ACK) are broadcast...

Comment: The RFC is the definition of the protocol. Books, like what you describe, are fine to get started, but you must read the RFCs to really understand the network protocols. There is much misinformation and confusion about network protocols running around, and there are texts with mistakes and some that that contradict each other. You will find myths, like you cannot use the all-zeroes or all-ones subnets, or current texts teaching network classes, despite the fact that all that was obsoleted by RFC 25 years ago, and modern networking doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange of DHCP message between  client and server can either be broadcast or unicast  depending on setting  of the fields inside in DHCP message in particular, broadcast flags field, client IP address (ciaddr) field and gateway IP address(giaddr) field.

Below is a summary note breakdown

*If broadcast flag field is set, the server will broadcast OFFER & ACK to client but only if client & server are in the same broadcast domain.

*If gateway IP address(giaddr) field is non-zero, there is relay agent between client & Server, therefore all server message are unicast to relay agent IP address.

*If  client IP address(ciaddr) field is non-zero, server will unicast OFFER & ACK to that client IP address

*If broadcast bit is not set, client IP address field is zero and gateway IP address field is zero, server will unicast DHCP message to client  hardware address (chaddr)

*If server identifier  IP address(siaddr) field is non-zero, client will send all message to that IP address in siaddr. This field will be non-zero in OFFER and ACK message because DHCP server will set it to identify it self.

https://www.niledigitech.com/447/dynamic-host-configuration-protocol/